# generate alert if someone trigger ad-hoc backup and it's not copy_only backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

We are using 3rd party tool to backup SQL server databases. I am looking to setup an alert which gets generated whenever Ad-hoc backup is taken and it's not copy_only. We are using 3rd party monitoring tool and I would like to setup an alert using this 3rd party tool which pulls an information using T-SQL script.

Alert should generated whenever T-SQL query return result 0 or 1 if ad-hoc backup taken in last 1 hour and it's not copy_only database backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to retrieve the normal information from your backup history on the relevant SQL Server instance, to find out what you normal backup file location looks like. You can achieve this with something like this:

```
SELECT  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
   CASE msdb..backupset.type  
       WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'  
       WHEN 'I' THEN 'Diff'
       WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'  
   END AS backup_type,  
   -- msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size / 1024 / 1024 as [backup_size MB],  
   CASE  
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 2 THEN 'Disk'
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 5 THEN 'Tape'
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 7 THEN 'Virtual Device' 
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 9 THEN 'Azure Storage' 
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 105 THEN 'A permanent backup device'
       ELSE 'Unknown backup device code:' + CAST(msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type AS VARCHAR(3)) + '!'    
   END AS device_type_desc,
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name,
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.description,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.is_copy_only,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.is_snapshot,   
   msdb.dbo.backupmediaset.name,
   msdb.dbo.backupmediaset.software_name,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.user_name,
   'EOR'  
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
       ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediaset
       ON msdb.dbo.backupmediaset.media_set_id = backupmediafamily.media_set_id
WHERE 1 = 1
ORDER BY msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date DESC;
```

A result set for when using Commvault as your backup solution could look like this:

> | database_name | backup_start_date | backup_type | device_type_desc | physical_device_name | logical_device_name | backupset_name | description | is_copy_only | is_snapshot | name | software_name | user_name |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | TVDTools | 2021-10-25 08:04:14.000 | Log | Virtual Device | 8e5bda3c-d453-4328-b180-dcee74549f68 | NULL | CommVault Galaxy Backup | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | Microsoft SQL Server | DOMAIN\USER |
> | TVDTools | 2021-10-24 21:01:58.000 | Log | Virtual Device | f40f904f-e197-4c2b-88fe-b9cdb5ee237f | NULL | CommVault Galaxy Backup | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | Microsoft SQL Server | DOMAIN\USER |
> | master | 2021-10-24 20:16:02.000 | Full | Virtual Device | 361ff522-8e39-406c-b971-5808ee51240b | NULL | CommVault Galaxy Backup | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | Microsoft SQL Server | DOMAIN\USER |
> | TVDTools | 2021-10-24 20:06:44.000 | Diff | Virtual Device | 3589d70e-af8d-469f-ad66-5e1ca52cef1e | NULL | CommVault Galaxy Backup | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | Microsoft SQL Server | DOMAIN\USER |
> | msdb | 2021-10-24 20:06:44.000 | Diff | Virtual Device | 12685e62-f688-4818-96d3-e20a802af6b9 | NULL | CommVault Galaxy Backup | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | Microsoft SQL Server | DOMAIN\USER |

So you have to determine with your backup solution which columns tell you when something is being run outside you backup solution.

In my case I'd just search for any backup set that didn't have `CommVault Galaxy%` in the `backupset_name` column and possibly which weren't using a `device_type` code of `7`. Your mileage may vary.

#### Answering Your Questions

Combining the above query with a couple of `WHERE` clauses would result in the following query, which you could possibly plug into your monitoring tool:

```
SELECT  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
   CASE msdb..backupset.type  
       WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'  
       WHEN 'I' THEN 'Diff'
       WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'  
   END AS backup_type,  
   -- msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size / 1024 / 1024 as [backup_size MB],  
   CASE  
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 2 THEN 'Disk'
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 5 THEN 'Tape'
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 7 THEN 'Virtual Device' 
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 9 THEN 'Azure Storage' 
       WHEN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type = 105 THEN 'A permanent backup device'
       ELSE 'Unknown backup device code:' + CAST(msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type AS VARCHAR(3)) + '!'    
   END AS device_type_desc,
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name,
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.description,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.is_copy_only,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.is_snapshot,   
   msdb.dbo.backupmediaset.name,
   msdb.dbo.backupmediaset.software_name,
   msdb.dbo.backupset.user_name,
   'EOR'  
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
       ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediaset
       ON msdb.dbo.backupmediaset.media_set_id = backupmediafamily.media_set_id
WHERE 1 = 1
-- Is Not CommVault Backup Check
AND (msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.device_type <> 7 
     AND msdb.dbo.backupset.name NOT LIKE 'CommVault Galaxy%')
-- Last Hour Check 
AND   (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102)) >= DATEADD(hh,-1,GETDATE())
-- Is Not Copy_Only Check
AND msdb.dbo.backupset.is_copy_only <> 1
ORDER BY msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date DESC;
```

Which results in the following output:

> | database_name | backup_start_date | backup_type | device_type_desc | physical_device_name | logical_device_name | backupset_name | description | is_copy_only | is_snapshot | name | software_name | user_name | (No column name) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | TVDTools | 2021-10-25 09:21:07.000 | Full | Disk | H:\adhoc\SERVERNAME\TVDTools_Full_CopyOnly_20211025_092107.bak | NULL | TVDTools-Full Backup | NULL | 0 | 0 | NULL | Microsoft SQL Server | DOMAIN/User | EOR |

Gotcha!

The results can be used in your monitoring software to do whatever you want to do, e.g. send an e-mail with the results, trigger an alarm in the console, ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [backupset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table in msdb. A sample query to get you started:

```
SELECT [database_name] AS [Database]
    , [user_name] AS [BackupCreator]
    , [backup_start_date] AS [BackupDate]
    , CASE [type]
        WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'
        WHEN 'I' THEN 'Diff'
        WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
      END AS [BackupType]
    , [is_copy_only] AS [IsCopyOnly]
FROM msdb..backupset
```

You may need to include [backupmediafamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupmediafamily-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you also want to find the location that the errant backup was taken.